# Spring security OAuth2 - how to disable access token expiry?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have requirement where in client makes API calls using the access token. Generating access token is one time job and I will be providing the access token to the client.I believe, the spring security has a expiry on the access token on expiry of which need to pass the request token to get a new access token. Is there a way to disable the expiry of access token, which enables the API access  with single access token always?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the API docs, you can set a [zero or negative value](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultTokenServices.html#setAccessTokenValiditySeconds%28int%29) for the access token validity if you don't want the token to expire.

Note that this will be overridden if you have set a specific value for the client.

Comment: Can this access token behave like a API KEY.. Once shared with the client and client can use it always irrespective of the fact of server restart?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "API KEY", but unless you use an in-memory store for the tokens, they should work beyond server restarts. You can use  a database or JWT tokens. Since you don't want them to expire, I would use a database so that you can revoke them more easily if needed.

Comment: can you disable expiry of Refresh token when server restarted...??